# grabbing an array value, but only the text - how?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to grab the value of an array that I got from parsing an xml file (using PHP's simpleXML) so that I can throw it into a database table. The problem I'm having is that one of the array values has a div and "a" tags in it after a sentence or two (which is what I really want). I'm not sure how to grab only the text. The array value looks like this:

```
[0] => The central purpose and philosophy of this podcast series<div class="feedflare">
```

So I'm assuming that maybe I could do some kind of function that grabs the value up to the point of the "<" and stop there and throw this new variable into the database. I'm kind of a n00b with PHP so I don't even know where to start doing that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is what you_re looking for. just do:

```
$text = strip_tags($my_array[0]);
```